# Can't use Sequential Model in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

This is the code:

```
def point_wise_feed_forward_network(d_model, dff):
  return tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(dff, activation='relu'),  # (batch_size, seq_len, dff)
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)  # (batch_size, seq_len, d_model)
  ])
```

I use it in a phew classes, initializating it as:

```py
class Foo(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
   def __init__(self, d_model, dff):
      super().__init__()
      self.net = point_wise_feed_forward_network(d_model, dff)
   ...
   
   def call(self, args):
      ... # getting prev_layer (which is a tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization() layer)
      var = self.net(prev_layer)
      ...
```

The main output error is:

```
ValueError: Weights for model decoder_sequential have not yet been created. Weights are created when the Model is first called on inputs or `build()` is called with an `input_shape`
```

```
File "<ipython-input-314-94b9d1a33527>", line 25, in train_step  *
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, transformer.trainable_variables)
    File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\tfm2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 2308, in trainable_variables
        return self.trainable_weights
    File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\tfm2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2104, in trainable_weights
        trainable_variables += trackable_obj.trainable_variables
    File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\tfm2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 2308, in trainable_variables
        return self.trainable_weights
    File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\tfm2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1357, in trainable_weights
        children_weights = self._gather_children_attribute('trainable_variables')
    File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\tfm2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 2915, in _gather_children_attribute
        return list(
    File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\tfm2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 2917, in <genexpr>
        getattr(layer, attribute) for layer in nested_layers))
    File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\tfm2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 2308, in trainable_variables
        return self.trainable_weights
    File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\tfm2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1357, in trainable_weights
        children_weights = self._gather_children_attribute('trainable_variables')
    File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\tfm2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 2915, in _gather_children_attribute
        return list(
    File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\tfm2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 2917, in <genexpr>
        getattr(layer, attribute) for layer in nested_layers))
    File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\tfm2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 2308, in trainable_variables
        return self.trainable_weights
    File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\tfm2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2099, in trainable_weights
        self._assert_weights_created()
    File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\tfm2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 471, in _assert_weights_created
        super(functional.Functional, self)._assert_weights_created()  # pylint: disable=bad-super-call
    File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\tfm2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2736, in _assert_weights_created
        raise ValueError(f'Weights for model {self.name} have not yet been '
```

So, I've initialized it in every class where it is used. Why does it say that I've not created the model?

PD: This error only comes out when I use `tf.GradientTape()`

PDD: [I'm following this Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer)

Comment: Don't you have to pass the input_shape for the first Dense invocation?

Comment: @MarkLavin no but earliers this worked out. Please watch the tutorial I'm doing

Comment: Instead of pointing to a tutorial, include your own code that reproduces the problem, as you are obviously doing something different.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy well, now it works. i've not touched nothing, i've just restarted my pc. seems like it was a "blackout" between dependencies;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the first layer in your model you need to pass in the input shape, for example (224,224,3)

````
tf.keras.layers.Dense(dff, activation='relu', input_shape=(224,224,3)
```
you also need to compile your model
````

Comment: hello Gerry, thx for answering. I've just restarted my pc and now it works so it has to be something related to dependencies.